# Firebase 4.3.0 play services resolver error

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I just installed `FirebaseMessaging.unitypackage` in Unity in a fresh project. First I updated version handler and got a success message, then I selected **"Play services resolver -> Android resolver -> Resolve"** and I got a following error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1.GenerateGradleProperties (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 properties)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1.GradleResolution (System.String destinationDirectory, System.String androidSdkPath, Boolean logErrorOnMissingArtifacts, System.Action`1 resolutionComplete)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1.DoResolutionUnsafe (Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport svcSupport, System.String destinationDirectory, System.Action resolutionComplete)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1+<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey3.<>m__0 ()
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1.UpdateTryResolution ()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:127)
```

Comment: what other plugins are you using?

Comment: @uzu None, that's why I made a fresh project, to eliminate that potential issue.

Comment: I just figured out that this works on mac, but not on windows, so they probably only have a bug on windows platform.